# In Drupal 7 how to expose TID (term id) as a selectable field on the manage display section of the taxonomy page?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

How can I expose the TID of a the term as a field via the manage display section of the taxonomy page?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: [Create a custom field formatter in Drupal 7](http://www.whenwhowhere.com/tech-blog/create-custom-field-formatter-drupal-7)

Comment: Also see the comment at the bottom of that article referring to the [Custom Formatters](https://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) module.

Comment: Custom formatter is kinda wrong for this, since it would have to hijack an existing field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds), and create a [custom field](https://drupal.org/node/1795314).

1. Install ds and ds_extras.
2. Configure ds_extras to enable custom fields.
3. Activate a display suite layout for your taxonomy term display.
4. Create a custom field, where you can put the tid as a token.

Comment: i dont see an options for "cutsom fields". I think you mean "code field" or "dynamic fields" in the fields tab. But what do I put there?

Comment: Check "Use tokens", and then try sth like [tid] or [taxonomy_term:tid]. There should be a list of available tokens.

Comment: You need to enable token module first, this could be a thing.